# int to long assignment

Tags: java, int, long-integer

I have been trying this int and long conversion where I have tried assigning an `int` variable to a `long` variable. The code is as follows:

```
public static void main(String []args){
    int i = 1024;
    long j = i;
    long k = i*i*i*i;
    System.out.println("j= " +j+ ", k= " +k);
}
```

So, while printing `j`, it simply gave an output of `1024`. But while printing `k`, it showed an overflow (`k`=0). I sorted out this problem by using this technique, where I have explicitly casted each `i` to `long`. i.e.

```
public static void main(String []args){
    int i = 1024;
    long j = i;
    long k = ((long)i)*((long)i)*((long)i)*((long)i);
    System.out.println("j= " +j+ ", k= " +k);
}
```

Now, it showed correct values of both `j` and `k`.
So, I wanted to know why is this needed to cast `int` in the second case but not in the first one. `k`, being a `long` can retain this value after this heavy assignment. But, why it is not been correctly assigned?

Comment: casting first `i` to long should be enough

Comment: The defective pattern you have identified -- a multiplication of integers that could overflow that is converted "too late" to a larger type -- is relatively common in both C# and Java; we find more than five instances per million lines of code analyzed. A related defect with a similar discovery rate is a division of two integers and a "too late" conversion to a double; people are often surprised that three hundred divided by five hundred and assigned to a double is zero, not 0.6.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The reason is that your line

```
long k = i*i*i*i;
```

can be thought of as

```
long k = ((i*i)*i)*i;
```

or...

```
int k1 = i*i;
int k2 = k1*i;
int k3 = k2*i;
long k = k3;
```

So when any of `kn` overflows, you get the error.

When you do your casts you're obviously circumventing this problem by always multiplying `long`s together.

Of course the simplest modification to your initial program is to define `i` as a `long` straight away, instead of an `int`.

```
long i = 1024L;
```

Comment: @dav_i , `k3` will be overflow because it is `int` variable, it must be `long`

Answer (score 7):

This problem is based on the fact that **different types use different amount of memory.** int and long are both Integers, the difference is that **int is 4 bytes**, while **long is 8 bytes**.

Lets modify your code a bit:

```
public class Test {


  public static void main(String []args){
        int i = 1024;
        long j = i;
        long k = i*i*i;

        System.out.println("My multipliers are of type int:");
        System.out.println("j= " +j+ ", k= " +k);           
        System.out.println("Is k less than Integer.MAX_VALUE: "  + (k < Integer.MAX_VALUE? "YES" : "NO"));
        k = i*i*i*i;
        System.out.println("j= " +j+ ", k= " +k);

        //now multiplying with j instead of i
        System.out.println("\nNow Im working with a long type:");
        k = j*j*j;
        System.out.println("j= " +j+ ", k= " +k);           
        System.out.println("Is k less than Integer.MAX_VALUE: "  + (k < Integer.MAX_VALUE? "YES" : "NO"));
        k = j*j*j*j;
        System.out.println("j= " +j+ ", k= " +k);
        System.out.println("Is k less than Integer.MAX_VALUE: "  + (k < Integer.MAX_VALUE? "YES" : "NO"));
        k = j*j*j*j;

     }

}
```

The code above shows that when you have multiplied i 3 times the result is a value that is smaller than Integer.MAX_VALUE (which is 2147483647), and when youre multiplying it 4 times the result is 0 since there is no enough place in the poor 4 bytes of the multipliers. :)
But you can see that when the multipliers (right side, j) are of type long, the correct value is printed, and the last printing shows that the statement k < Integer.MAX_VALUE is false, which is the reason for your zero. :)

Answer (score 6):

`i*i*i*i` is an all int multiplication so the resultant is integer only (Which is overflowing in your case). for a long resultant you only need to convert one of them to long so this is sufficient

```
long k = ((long)i)*i*i*i;
```

Comment: Does associativity come into play here? I meant, if it is right associative, then, if it crosses the integer_max_value previously before coming to the (long i), it will show an overflow again in your case.

Comment: try it @ShashishChandra

Comment: I have tried it, and thanks to you, it worked out. I was just asking, is there any role of associativity here?

Comment: Yes, there is .. try converting the last one to long instead of first one. you will see.

Comment: So, it is left associative and it will work that way only. Thanks for your reply, I really appreciate it.

Comment: There seems to be a little problem here: pls look here: http://ideone.com/fork/gdvZ5y
It also works the other way round since `i*i*i` < Integer_max_value. :)

Comment: Yes, It will work in that case. because the fourth multiplication with `i` takes it beyond `Integer.MaxValue`. So both approach will work. but if you chose `i` higher so that three multiplication goes beyond `Integer.MaxValue`, you will see the behavior.

Answer (score 2):

In first the value of i is an int and the integer multipllication happening and `i*i*i*i` result is integer and hence the [`integer overflow.`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow)

Where as in second case you are explicitly telling/making the result as `long`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It is really helpful. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

`1099511627776` which is the result of multiplication is `>Integer.MAX_VALUE` as it's Integer Multiplication so after `i*i*i` value would be `1073741824` but after multiplication with `1024`  it becomes out of range which causes [integer overflow](http://www.mkyong.com/java/javas-silent-killer-buffer-overflow-careful/) and k will be 0.

- You can cast one of the `i` to `long`
- Multiply with `1L` (`1L*i*i*i*i`) But NOT `i*i*i*i*1L`
- You can also assign `i*i*i` to long and than multiply with `i` like this `long k =(k=i*i*i)*i;`