# Converting negative Integer.MIN to positive long

Tags: java, int

I am trying to convert negative Integer.MIN to positive long value using below code :

```
long lv = -1 * value_int;
```

Above code works perfectly except when value of value_int = Integer.MIN_VALUE. In Integer.MIN_VALUE case, value of lv is always Integer.MIN_VALUE;

Below code work in all cases including Integer.MIN_VALUE

```
long lv = value_int;
lv = -1 * value_int;
```

Any idea why long lv = -1 * value_int does not work in Integer.MIN_VALUE case?

Comment: @Oleg that's a C# question/answer. Although in this case, the problem is likely quite similar, it's not a good duplicate.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt You're probably right. Found another one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24755629/int-to-long-assignment though also not a perfect fit. I should probably just stop wasting my time flagging duplicates and answer obvious ones instead, if nobody cares about the quality of content here, why should I? (just ranting, not directed at you)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`1` (preceded by the unary `-` operator, in this case) is an `int` literal. Since `value_int` is also an `int`, the multiplication is done as an `int` - which overflows, and only then promoted to a long. If you use a `long` literal instead, the multiplication will be done as a long, and you'd get the correct result:

```
long lv = -1L * value_int;
// Here-----^
```

Comment: This is a very pedantic point, but according to the JLS -1 is not an int literal. It’s the int literal 1 preceded by the unary operator -.

Comment: Nice catch @cppbeginner, thanks! Edited my answer accordingly.